# Is there a connection between "conjugation" and "a conjugate"?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

Given any sort of binomial $x+y$, its *conjugate* (noun) is the result of changing the sign of on of the summands: $x-y$. But then we also *conjugate* (verb) an element by another: the transformation $y \mapsto xyx^{-1}$ is conjugation $x$. Are these related, or are we just overloading this word?

Comment: See [Conjugation: mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugation) for several uses.

Comment: And see [CONJUGATE](https://jeff560.tripod.com/c.html) for historical source.

Comment: There isn't much of a distinction between verb and noun here. We conjugate $x+y$ to get $x-y$, and $xyx^{-1}$ is the (or rather _a_) conjugate of $y$.